# SUID executable doesn't work for `/dev/mem` access

Tags: raspbian, peripherals, qt

[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51375/how-to-allow-i2c-access-for-non-root-users) is explained how to gain access to the peripheral without being root.
I've just tried in my environment (Raspbian Stretch, RPi2, Qt5.9) in this way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setSetuidAllowed(true);
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyServer server;   
    return a.exec();
}
```

then, on the target:

```
$ sudo chown root:root MyServer
$ sudo chmod u+s MyServer
```

but running it as normal user leads to a segmentation fault. Here's the output of gdb:

```
$ gdb MyServer 
...
run(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/bin/MyServer 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
bcm2835_init: Unable to open /dev/mem: Operation not permitted
...
```

Am I missing some steps?

Comment: Try throwing an explicit `seteuid()` call in and see whether it succeeds (and/or use `geteuid()` to check).

Comment: Is this not enough? `$ ls -l -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 3322439 Oct  2 16:35 MyServer`

Comment: Furthermore if I don't set the `SetuidAllowed` to true, it refuses to start saying: " "FATAL: The application binary appears to be running setuid, this is a security hole." Hence I assume it succeeded.